# Merge Sort Python - Problems with sort function

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to get this merge sort algorithm to work and I'm totally stumped as to why it wont.  The merge function seems to work fine, but the sort function does not seem to work.  I've scoured the web for a solution, but I can't seem to find out what I am doing wrong.  I should mention that I am rather new to python and coding in general so any help would be appreciated.  The python code is provided below:

```
def sort(sorted_list):
    if len(sorted_list) <= 1:
        return sorted_list

    middle = len(sorted_list) // 2
    left = sorted_list[:middle]
    right = sorted_list[middle:]
    left = sort(left)
    right = sort(right)
    return sorted_list(merge(left, right))

def merge(a_list, b_list):
    combined_list = []
    index_a = 0
    index_b = 0
    length_a = len(a_list)
    length_b = len(b_list)

    while index_a < length_a or index_b < length_b:
        if index_a < length_a and index_b < length_b:
            if a_list[index_b] <= b_list[index_b]:
                combined_list += [a_list[index_a]]
                index_a = index_a + 1
            else:
                combined_list += [b_list[index_b]]
                index_b = index_b + 1
        elif index_a < length_a:
            combined_list += [a_list[index_a]]
            index_a = index_a +1
        else:
            combined_list += [b_list[index_b]]
            index_b = index_b + 1
    return combined_list
```

Comment: You probably got an error message saying `'list' object is not callable`, pointing to `return sorted_list(merge(left, right))`. Take a look at that line. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what's wrong:

`return sorted_list(merge(left, right))`

It should be:

`return merge(left, right)`

Also, not related to your error, but this line should be corrected:

`if a_list[index_b] <= b_list[index_b]:`

to:
`if a_list[index_a] <= b_list[index_b]:`

Answer (score 1):

I've made several fixes to your program. Here's the fixed program.

```
def sort(sorted_list):
    if len(sorted_list) <= 1:
        return sorted_list

    middle = len(sorted_list) // 2
    left = sorted_list[:middle]
    right = sorted_list[middle:]

    left = sort(left)
    right = sort(right)
    return merge(left, right)

def merge(a_list, b_list):
    combined_list = []
    index_a = 0
    index_b = 0
    length_a = len(a_list)
    length_b = len(b_list)

    while index_a < length_a and index_b < length_b:

        if a_list[index_a] <= b_list[index_b]:
            combined_list.append(a_list[index_a])
            index_a = index_a + 1
        else:
            combined_list.append(b_list[index_b])
            index_b = index_b + 1

    while index_a < length_a:
        combined_list.append(a_list[index_a])
        index_a = index_a + 1
    while index_b < length_b:
        combined_list.append(b_list[index_b])
        index_b = index_b + 1
  return combined_list

print sort([5,1,2])
```